# Why does saving dataset to Impala and loading it back yield no rows?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, impala, apache-spark-sql

1. Create Spark dataframe selecting from an Impala table

   ```
   sql_df1 = hive_context.sql("SELECT * FROM database1.table1 LIMIT 10")
   ```

1.1 This dataframe returns row count 10 and shows correct data: sql_df1

```
    print(sql_df1.count())
    sql_df1.show()
```

2. create a new table from the first Spark dataframe

   sql_df1.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").saveAsTable("database1.table2")
3. Refresh Metadata in impala, In HUE i can see database1.table2 has 10 rows of correct data
4. Create new Spark dataframe with the new table.

   ```
   sql_df2 = hive_context.sql("SELECT * FROM database1.table2 LIMIT 10")
   ```
5. ISSUE: The new sql_df2 has no rows, only headers.

   ```
   print(sql_df2.count())
   sql_df2.show()
   ```

Comment: I found the problem, the format has to be "hive" and not parquet.

Comment: Nice catch! I learnt something new today from you! Answer your question and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the format has to be "hive" and not parquet.